# Why does Xcode project always fail on first run but works on the second?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The question might not sound correctly worded but I don't know how to else put it, Apologies.
I am using `Google Maps API` in my project, to fetch the results and put them in a `CollectionView` using the `MSPeekCollectionViewDelegateImplementation POD`
Please any help is so much appreciated!

Always on the first run, as seen in the picture below, it never shows up.

[image]

On the second run however it works perfectly, as seen below:

[image]

API manager class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class GoogleMapsAPIManager {
    
    var bloodBanksArray = [BloodBanksModel]()
    
    
    func fetchCity(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees, raduis: Double){
        let urlString = "\(K.googleMapsAPI)&location=\(latitude),\(longitude)&radius=\(raduis)&key=\(K.apiKey)"
        print(urlString)
        performRequest(with: urlString)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Decoding JSON
    func performRequest(with urlString: String){
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeData = data {
                    self.parseJSON(bloodBankData: safeData)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSON(bloodBankData: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(BloodBanksData.self, from: bloodBankData)
            for i in 0...decodedData.results.count - 1 {
                bloodBanksArray.append(BloodBanksModel(name: decodedData.results[i].name, photo: decodedData.results[i].photos?[0].photoReference ?? "ATtYBwJjqXlw3DMdL74SRtgG_GRA3LkAET6hDJXHWtkQMaOTo1B3Gx9jrDTXFLFabGStSxX8BiYdLAnknF7A9ynw33KKyUh5Oc55A9vXzo_6nd4mnk5Sx-iOqMNaw21dk0C424PWaio9GiogQaKecYxOT1q-bmj30syypZmyxkjF7r3-gFyC", open_now: decodedData.results[i].openingHours?.openNow ?? false, longitude: decodedData.results[i].geometry.location.lng, latitude: decodedData.results[i].geometry.location.lat, vincinity: decodedData.results[i].vicinity, rating: decodedData.results[i].rating, placeId: decodedData.results[i].placeId, lat: decodedData.results[i].geometry.location.lat, lng: decodedData.results[i].geometry.location.lng))
            }
            
            print("bossins \(bloodBanksArray)")
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Blood banks Model:

```
import Foundation
struct BloodBanksModel {
    let name: String
    let photo: String
    let open_now: Bool
    let longitude: Double
    let latitude: Double
    let vincinity: String
    let rating: Double
    let placeId: String
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
}
```

Blood Bank Data:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - BloodBanksData
struct BloodBanksData: Codable {
    let results: [Result]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case results
    }
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let geometry: Geometry
    let name: String
    let openingHours: OpeningHours?
    let photos: [Photo]?
    let rating: Double
    let vicinity: String
    let placeId: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case geometry, name
        case openingHours = "opening_hours"
        case photos
        case rating
        case vicinity
        case placeId = "place_id"
    }
}

// MARK: - Geometry
struct Geometry: Codable {
    let location: Location
}

// MARK: - Location
struct Location: Codable {
    let lat, lng: Double
}

// MARK: - OpeningHours
struct OpeningHours: Codable {
    let openNow: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case openNow = "open_now"
    }
}

// MARK: - Photo
struct Photo: Codable {
    let photoReference: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case photoReference = "photo_reference"
    }
}
```

The `VC`:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var googleMapsAPIManager = GoogleMapsAPIManager()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        var currentLocation: CLLocation!

        if
           CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
           CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() ==  .authorizedAlways
        {
            currentLocation = locationManager.location
            googleMapsAPIManager.fetchCity(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, raduis: 2000.0)
        }
configureCollectionView()
}

func configureCollectionView() {
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: K.BloodBanks.bloodBanksCellNibName, bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(cellNib,
                                forCellWithReuseIdentifier: K.BloodBanks.bloodBankCellIdentifier)
        
        behavior = MSCollectionViewPeekingBehavior(cellSpacing: 20)
        behavior = MSCollectionViewPeekingBehavior(cellPeekWidth: 40)
        behavior = MSCollectionViewPeekingBehavior(minimumItemsToScroll: 1)
        behavior = MSCollectionViewPeekingBehavior(maximumItemsToScroll: 3)
        behavior = MSCollectionViewPeekingBehavior(numberOfItemsToShow: 1)
        
        collectionView.configureForPeekingBehavior(behavior: behavior)
        
    }
}
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource Methods
extension LandingViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return googleMapsAPIManager.bloodBanksArray.count
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: K.BloodBanks.bloodBankCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BloodBanksCell
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.bloodBankName.text = self.googleMapsAPIManager.bloodBanksArray[indexPath.row].name
            cell.bloodBankImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(K.googleMapsImageAPI)&photoreference=\(self.googleMapsAPIManager.bloodBanksArray[indexPath.row].photo)&key=\(K.apiKey)"), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bloodbank4"))
        }
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate Methods
extension LandingViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        behavior.scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView, withVelocity: velocity, targetContentOffset: targetContentOffset)
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like an asynchronous issue. You have to add a completion handler to `fetchCity` and reload the collection view when it's being called.

Comment: @vadian okay let me google that and I'll check, thank you for your reply

Comment: nevermind it keeps bugging.